# como hacer para que al recargar una pagina en angular no se pierdan los datos de la vista

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando resolver este problema que se me presento. estoy haciendo una peticion a una API junto con unos parametros de un formulario, estos parametros los paso a la otra vista donde defino la ruta asi:  de la siguiente manera:

```html
{ path: 'inmuebles',component: VistaInmuebleComponent}
```

```html
(click)="filtro(formulario.value)" [routerLink]="['/inmuebles']" [queryParams]="{tipo: formulario.controls['tipo'].value,transaccion: formulario.controls['transaccion'].value,pais: formulario.controls['pais'].value,cuartos: formulario.controls['cuartos'].value,precio_min: formulario.controls['precio_min'].value,precio_max: formulario.controls['precio_max'].value}"
```

La respuesta de esa API la guardo en una estructura de datos de un servicio y dicho servicio lo consumo en la vista: VistaInmuebleComponent. el problema es que si yo recargo la vista VistaInmuebleComponent los datos se pierden, estaba pensando era en guardar los datos en el localStorage pero como haria para pasarle los datos a la funcion donde hago la peticion a la API para solicitar los datos? en el .ts hago la peticion asi:

```js
    return this.hostlistService.filtroEspecifico(datosForm).subscribe(result => {
      result.data.first_page_url != null ? this.hostlistService.paginaPrim = result.data.first_page_url : this.hostlistService.paginaPrim = '';
    },error => {
            console.log(error);
    });
```

donde datosForm es el formulario, para poder pasar los valores de los campos a la petición de la API. como podría hacer para que al recargar vuelva a recargar los datos de la vista.

Estoy comenzando en Angular, estaria agradecido con la persona que pueda ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te sirva esto:

```
setData() {
    const objDataFilter = {
        'val1': 'value1',
        'val2': 'value2',
    };
    localStorage.setItem('formDataFilter', JSON.stringify(objDataFilter));
}

getData() {
    this.dataObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formDataFilter'));
    console.log(this.dataObj);
    console.log(this.dataObj.val1);
    console.log(this.dataObj.val2);
}
```

Mandas a llamar getData cuando necesites obtener la data de formDataFilter siempre y cuando se halla seteado previamente la data de formDataFilter.

Comment: Hola @Hacko, gracias por responder, asi lo termine haciendo, aunque no use JSON.stringify, lo hice bien inefeciente haciendo varios localStorage.setItem para cada parametro. Ahora tengo otra duda, a ver si me puedes echar una mano. como haria para que la url se actualice cada vez que filtro? ahorita estoy filtrando y me muestra los resulatdos pero la URL no cambia, siempre queda con la URL inicial. estaba itentando subscribirme al paramMap para detectar cambios pero me retorna NULL, no se por que. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes que trabajar con objetos y usar etiquetas de angular [(ngModel)]

seria algo como se muestra a continuación

```
 <td  *ngIf="!countryDef.readonly"class="text-center"><input class="admin-country-input-text"type="text" name="countryEnrDesc" [(ngModel)]="country.descCountry" disabled></td>
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por responder. No entiendo que hace esa linea que colocaste, lo que estaba pensando era, en el OnInit llamar a la funcion donde hago la peticion a la API y pasar los parametros que paso a traves de la URL de alguna forma. pero como podria pasar esos parametros a donde hago la peticion get? actualmente hago esto: "filtro(formulario.value)" dode formulario.value son los valores del formulario, pero como podria pasar todos los parametros de la url al metodo que hace la peticion post?

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal Julian se me ocurre una idea de que crees otra ruta con los parametros que quieras pasar

```
{ path: 'inmuebles/:algo/:texto:/id',component: VistaInmuebleComponent}
```

Esto lo puedes recibir con el activated Route y puedes guardar esos params en unas variables.

Comment: Hola @Alexis , gracias por responder. Algo asi lo tengo. y ya resolvi parte del problema. ahora bien, en esa vista tengo paginacion, pero cuando hago click en "siguiente" los parametros en la URL de la vista no se actualizan, siempre queda la misma URL, como podria hacer para actualizarlos a medida que se van modificando parametros en el filtro o cuando se hace click en los botones del a paginacion?